# Problem with creating a view in mySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've got a weird problem. When creating a view in the workbench my code gets transformed into a single line. I have no idea why. And no idea how to fix it. I did nothing special honestly. Just right clicked on Views and selected Create View. I wrote the code there and after clicking apply the code simply transformed (and always does that, but only on one view I'm creating, other Views work fine and code is readable) into a single line. Which is horrible if you'd agree, almost completely unreadable. So I was wondering if anyone faced this problem and even better if you know how would I fix it.

Edit:

After some testing I found that the line that causes this is in the select part of code:

```
round(avg(cast(datediff(sysdate(), a.birthdate) as float))/365.242199, 2) as averageAge
```

And some more info. I'm working with AdventureWorks database, that I think is from 2005.

Comment: i can't reproduce it in the new tab i add (SELECT * FROM abc) and i can beatify it  and when i choose the alter view it gets transforemd but only the * is made in a complete text. Which workbench version are you using?

Comment: The version is 8.0.27. I just found out that this line is the cause of that weird code transformation. If I leave it out of select, everything looks normal after clicking apply:
round(avg(cast(datediff(sysdate(), a.birthdate) as float))/365.242199, 2) as averageAge

Comment: maybe qa bug, when you post ot also add your table and a example for the view as they also want a [mre]

Comment: I'm actually working with adventureworks database (from 2005 I think). And for the entire view I'm using 4 tables. But it's probably a weird bug. As only removing that one thing from select solved the issue. But when I re-add it I the code again transforms to a single line. But still, I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just removed the "cast...as float" from the code and now I'm getting the readable format and not a single line after hitting apply. And obviously the values I'm getting are still correct. I don't know why that bug happened/happens but this solved my issue.

Comment: as i said make a bug report